# Git branching strategy, how to push to various environments without issues

Tags: git, continuous-integration, branching-and-merging

Looking for advice on how to setup git to support multiple developers working on features, and how we push to our various environments like dev, qa and uat.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
dev_branch
- new features get a feature branch i.e. dev_branch_feature_x
- once feature is completed, it gets merged into the dev_branch
- dev_branch then merges into main_branch

main_branch
- code must be merged into main to push to UAT
- once uat is signed off, it gets pushed to production
```

One issue is, does having a feature_branch mean that we need seperate dev and qa environments for each feature_branch?

If 2 developers are working on a feature, they can't directly push their changes to the QA environment because they will write over each other.
And I'm not sure if they could merge both changes into the same branch and then push as they might have conflicts.

Is the above branching model workable or do you suggest something else?

Comment: The second person to push code doesn't "overwrite" the first person's changes, his push fails telling him he must first pull and perform a merge before he can push.

Comment: @meagar but if the feature branches are breaking changes, you can't expect them to pull, so I guess it depends sometimes you need a seperate evvironment to push to no?

Comment: Your developers shouldn't be pushing code so broken that they don't want others to pull it. Pushing, in Git, *requires* others to pull. You can't use Git if you can't accept that basic fact.

Answer (score 1):

A very popular workflow for use with git is described in http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Basically, what you are most successful doing is to have a development environment that is on a long-running branch, which can be the trunk if you wish or can be a separate branch, in this document one named 'develop'.

Issue branches and development branches would be branched off from this, developed and tested, and then merged back when the author believes they are stable.  Then if whatever testing you require in development to qualify it to go to the next test level passes, you tag and build that and deploy it into the test environment.

When you are getting close to a release, you would branch from the running development branch for a release branch, which then is only touched to improve its stability for release.  This makes it a dead-end branch, but a great place to apply hot-fixes later.

And if you are in one of those places that wants the trunk to be the most recent version deployed to production, then whenever something has passed all testing and is deployed to production, you merge it onto the trunk.  This is option; in my opinion it is unnecessary overhead and complexity, but it is a Management Demand you run into quite often.